# How do I retrieve the value of a string from a list of .cs files?

Tags: c#, search

I have a list of .cs files, each of which contain a string commandID. I need to retrieve the value of this string.

How do I implement this search and retrieve value mechanism in C#?

Comment: Is this Winform or Asp.net? Also, do you want to read the files using the FileSystem?

Comment: What have you tried this far? What part are you stuck on? Are you stuck on finding the files, opening the files, searching the files?

Comment: as of now im stuck with retrieving the value of the string . I am able to get to the line holding the string , now i need the value of the string .

Comment: @AmmaraGafoor I solved your retrieving CommandID problem in my answer, and also tested the code, take a look.

Answer (score 3):

```
    //Sample code to list all .cs files within a directory
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.cs");


    // Sample code to read 1 file. 
    // Read each line of the file into a string array. Each element 
    // of the array is one line of the file. 
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\file1.cs");

    // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // INSERT YOUR SEARCH LOGIC HERE
    }
```

Comment: Excellent! You beat me to it!

Comment: I did exactly the same :) looked back here ..and saw your answer :) thanks !

Comment: once i get the line , how do i get it to return the value ... in the sense , the string im searching for , i need the value it holds.

Comment: i am assuming the string is of type integer ? Then all you need to do is: 

int value = int.Parse(line);

Comment: You should probably use int.TryParse so that you can handle an error case.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that, there is some string named CommandId in your .Cs files in your project and you are trying to get the value of it because you donot want to manually go to each file and get its value.

Follow the following

1- Paste all the .CS files in a separate folder.

2- Use FileSytem to get all the files in that folder

3- Use stream reader to get the text in the .cs files

4- compare each line in the file with the text you want to find.

5- If the string matches, the save it somewhere like XML or another text file.

6- Read the next file and Go back to step 3.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the ID out of it :)
let's say you have found the line you want, so I get the ID out of the line like :

```
string line = "while(i<10){CommandID = 15852; i+=1;}";
//I've put a complicated code in the string to make you sure
var rightSideOfAssignment = line.Split(new string[] {"CommandID"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
int val = 0,temp;
bool hasAlreadyStartedFetchingNumbers= false;
foreach (char ch in rightSideOfAssignment)  //iterate each charachter
{
    if (int.TryParse(ch.ToString(), out temp)) //if ch is a number
    {
        foundFirstInteger = true;
        val *= 10;
        val += temp;
    }
    else
    {
        if (hasAlreadyStartedFetchingNumbers)
            break;
        //If you don't check this condition, it'll result to 158521
        //because after hitting `;` it won't stop searching
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(val.ToString()); //shows 15852
```